# Object of class Carbon\Carbon could not be converted to number

Tags: laravel

I am trying to multiply two numbers in laravel which are double type. but it is giving the error 'Object of class Carbon\Carbon could not be converted to number'. How can I fix this error?

```html
if($data['price'] != null || $data['price'] != 0){
    $target->unit_price = $data['price'];
    $target->total_price = $data['price']* $data['qty'];
}else{
    $target->unit_price =0;
    $target->total_price = 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like what you have in `$data['price']` or `$data['qty']` is a **Carbon date object**. You should use `dump()` method to see what are the contents of the `$data` variable.